# How to propertly pass query string parameters? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to send an HTTP request with parameters via a query

Example:

```
  URL: https://api/endpoint?d=1&value=2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How will i pass query parameters to REST API inside a service in an angular application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934132/how-will-i-pass-query-parameters-to-rest-api-inside-a-service-in-an-angular-appl)

Comment: Your both parameters are with the same name. Change them to value1 and value2

Answer (score 0):

To add params for your URL, you need to create the correct options, for example:

```
const options = { params: new HttpParams().set('value1', '1').set('value2', '2') };
return this.http.get(`${APP_BASE_URL}/endpoint`, options);
```

Before is an example, you can create a petition with params of many ways.

Check the documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-params)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and pass it as 2nd parameter in get method.

```
const url="example.com/data";
const parameters = {
  'value1': 1,
  'value2': 2
};
return this.httpClient.get(url, {
  params: parameters
})
```

This will create your url like below:-

```
URL: https://api/endpoint?value1=1&value2=2
```